# Python Selenium can't go through links. Pastebin Crawling

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-crawler, pastebin

Hello I am trying to extract all the links, over the 10 pages I am given, for the search `ssh`.

I can extract the first 10 links from the first page, after loading the JavaScripts, then, I am able to click once, the first page, and extract the next 10 links, but, when trying the go to the third page, I get an error.

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import requests
import re

links = []
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://pastebin.com/search?q=ssh")

# wait for the search results to be loaded
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".gsc-result-info")))
for link in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='gs-title']/a[@class='gs-title']"):
        if link.get_attribute("href") != None:
            print link.get_attribute("href")
# get all search results links
for page in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='gsc-cursor-page']"):
    driver.implicitly_wait(10) # seconds
    page.click()

    for link in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='gs-title']/a[@class='gs-title']"):
        if link.get_attribute("href") != None:
            print link.get_attribute("href")
```

And this is what I am able to obtain, as well as the error I take:

```
python pastebinselenium.py 
http://pastebin.com/u/ssh
http://pastebin.com/gsQWBEZP
http://pastebin.com/gfA12TWk
http://pastebin.com/udWMWdPR
http://pastebin.com/J55238CB
http://pastebin.com/DN2aHvRr
http://pastebin.com/f0rh66kU
http://pastebin.com/3zvY3DSm
http://pastebin.com/fqHVJGEm
http://pastebin.com/3aB7h0fm
http://pastebin.com/3uBAxXu3
http://pastebin.com/cxjRqeSh
http://pastebin.com/5nJPNr3Q
http://pastebin.com/qV0rPNfP
http://pastebin.com/zubt2Yc7
http://pastebin.com/jFrjWYpE
http://pastebin.com/DU7yqjQ1
http://pastebin.com/AFtWHmtE
http://pastebin.com/UVP5behK
http://pastebin.com/hP7XTyv1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pastebinselenium.py", line 21, in <module>
    page.click()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 74, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 457, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 233, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up
Stacktrace:
    at fxdriver.cache.getElementAt (resource://fxdriver/modules/web-element-cache.js:9454)
    at Utils.getElementAt (file:///tmp/tmpzhZSEC/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:9039)
    at fxdriver.preconditions.visible (file:///tmp/tmpzhZSEC/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:10090)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.checkPreconditions_ (file:///tmp/tmpzhZSEC/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12644)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///tmp/tmpzhZSEC/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12661)
    at fxdriver.Timer.prototype.setTimeout/<.notify (file:///tmp/tmpzhZSEC/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:625)
```

I want to take the 10 links from the 10 pages (100 in total) and I am only able to extract 20 =(

I have also tried this:

```
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".gsc-cursor-box")))
```

right before the `click`, but no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea would be to click the pagination links in a loop waiting for the next page number to become active collecting links on the way. Implementation:

```
from pprint import pprint

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://pastebin.com/search?q=ssh")

# wait for the search results to be loaded
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".gsc-result-info")))

links = [link.get_attribute("href") for link in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".gsc-results .gs-result > .gsc-thumbnail-inside > .gs-title > a.gs-title")]
for page_number in range(2, 11):
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='gsc-cursor-page' and . = '%d']" % page_number).click()

    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'gsc-cursor-current-page') and . = '%d']" % page_number)))

    links.extend([link.get_attribute("href") for link in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".gsc-results .gs-result > .gsc-thumbnail-inside > .gs-title > a.gs-title")])

print(len(links))
pprint(links)
```

Prints:

```
100
['http://pastebin.com/u/ssh',
 'http://pastebin.com/gsQWBEZP',
  ...
 'http://pastebin.com/vtBgrndi',
 'http://pastebin.com/WgXrebLq',
 'http://pastebin.com/Nxui56Gh',
 'http://pastebin.com/Qef0LZPR',
 'http://pastebin.com/yNUh1fRe',
 'http://pastebin.com/2j0d8FzL',
 'http://pastebin.com/g92A2jAq']
```

Comment: That works. Thank you very much !!
But I don't understand why it doesn't work with this line: `wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".gsc-cursor-box")))`
and it does with:
`wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'gsc-cursor-current-page') and . = '%d']" % page_number)))`
The idea is the same: Wait until the pagination is ready before clicking next time

Comment: @aDoN that's exactly what the trick here is - the first condition would be immediately satisfied since the element with `gsc-cursor-box` is present on every page and immediately available. The latter is more focused - we are waiting for a specific page number link in the pagination section to become active - that would mean we've advanced to the next page..hope that helps to understand the solution. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, but it seems you are waiting for the current page you are on, not the next page, isn't it¿?

Comment: @aDoN nope, waiting for the next page. Say, clicking "2" and waiting for "2" become an active page link..

Comment: ahhh become active, which means, you are actually on the 2nd link and you can click the 3rd one¿?

Comment: @aDoN yup! I suggest either debug the code line by line or add intermediate prints to get a clearer picture of what is going on.

Comment: Perfect yeah I understand what you did, one last thing: the `.` in the `//div[@class='gsc-cursor-page' and . = '%d']` means the "content/text" of the element, doens't it ¿? Thank u

Comment: @aDoN yup, the `.` refers to the text of the current node.